# Javascript, get input value in prev td

Tags: javascript

I have a table with two inputs per row and I am trying to calculate the difference between each input for that row and display it in the 3rd column.

I have looked around and tried answers from 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782243/get-input-value-in-javascript-without-using-jquery), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865340/javascript-cannot-get-input-value), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343589/javascript-getting-the-value-of-an-input-in-a-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823070/how-to-retrieve-value-of-input-type-in-a-dynamic-table) as well as others and none seem to work for me.

```js
$(".calibration_input_lin").blur(function(){
  var input = $(this)
  var val = input.val()
  var row = input.parents('tr').eq(0)

  var req = input.closest('td').prev().val()
  var res = $(".resolution").data("resolution")


  var diff = difference = val - req
  var diff = diff.toFixed(res)

  $.ajax({
    url: "<%= customer_asset_calibration_header_path(@customer,@asset,@calibration_header) %>",
    data: { value: val }

  }).done(function( response ) {
    row.find(".calibration_lin_input_diff").text(diff)
    window.alert(req);
  });

  // or you can run some JS code here to calculate difference
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-sm linearity">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Weights</th>
            <th>Required</th>
            <th>Actual</th>
            <th>Difference</th>
            <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="calibration_input_req"><input step="any" required="required" value="0.000" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2677][required]" id="result_id_2677_required" /></td>
              <td><input step="any" required="required" id="linearity_actual" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2677][actual]" /></td>  
              <td> class ="calibration_lin_input_diff"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="calibration_input_req"><input step="any" required="required" value="0.005" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2678][required]" id="result_id_2678_required" /></td>
              <td><input step="any" required="required" id="linearity_actual" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2678][actual]" /></td>  
              <td> class ="calibration_lin_input_diff"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="calibration_input_req"><input step="any" required="required" value="0.050" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2679][required]" id="result_id_2679_required" /></td>
              <td><input step="any" required="required" id="linearity_actual" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2679][actual]" /></td>  
              <td> class ="calibration_lin_input_diff"></td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <table>
```

I use the same script elsewhere and it works fine when the `req` variable is static accross all table rows. I just can't seem to get it to pick up the input in td 2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var row = input.closest('tr')`

Comment: Hi why do you use `$(".calibration_input_lin").blur`? As I understand do you need to iterate through all rows and calculate the difference between first 2 fields in the row?

Comment: Hi @KirillNovikov that was provided to me in a suggestion by someone else. I do not need to iterate through all rows, just the row that is being updated,

Comment: @mplungjan when I replace my `var row = input.parents('tr').eq(0)` with `
var row = input.closest('tr')` it still doesn't recognise the input of the 2nd td  (class calibration_input_req).

Comment: I changed the line `var req = input.parents('td').siblings('td').find('input').val();` to `var req = input.parents('td').prev().find('input').val();` and it works - get in! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `blur` you can use `input`. You can target the parent to get the `prev()` td's input value on each input change.

You have to set initial value as `0` when there is no value exist in the `input`. You can do so by using ternary operator.

There is no element with `.resolution` in the HTML whose data is used in `toFixed()`.

You can try the following way:

```js
$(".calibration_input_lin").on('input', function(){
  var input = $(this)
  var val = input.val()? input.val() : 0;
  var row = input.parents('tr').eq(0)

  var req = input.parents('td').prev('td').find('input').val();
  req = req ? req : 0;
  //var res = $(".resolution").data("resolution")

  var diff = val - req;
  var diff = diff.toFixed(2);

  $(this).parents('tr').find('.calibration_lin_input_diff').text(diff);

  // or you can run some JS code here to calculate difference
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-sm linearity">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Weights</th>
            <th>Required</th>
            <th>Actual</th>
            <th>Difference</th>
            <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="calibration_input_req"><input step="any" required="required" value="0.000" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2677][required]" id="result_id_2677_required" /></td>
              <td><input step="any" required="required" id="linearity_actual" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2677][actual]" /></td>  
              <td class ="calibration_lin_input_diff"></td>
              <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="calibration_input_req"><input step="any" required="required" value="0.005" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2678][required]" id="result_id_2678_required" /></td>
              <td><input step="any" required="required" id="linearity_actual" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2678][actual]" /></td>  
              <td class ="calibration_lin_input_diff"></td>
              <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="calibration_input_req"><input step="any" required="required" value="0.050" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2679][required]" id="result_id_2679_required" /></td>
              <td><input step="any" required="required" id="linearity_actual" class="form-control calibration_input_lin" type="number" name="result_id[2679][actual]" /></td>  
              <td class ="calibration_lin_input_diff"></td>
              <td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <table>
```

Comment: When I add the line `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
` to my page it knocks out the formatting for chosen selector which resides in the 1st td - have you seen that?

Also in the first TD is also an input will that impact your answer?

Comment: Yes becuase it was a large amount of code repeated I took it out, but on my page there is an selector input in that td with about 100 options to choose from.

Comment: @ChrisNash, without seeing the full context it is really difficult to answer precisely.....

Comment: `$(this).closest('td').next().text(diff);` is a lot shorter

Comment: @mplungjan, `.next()` is not working when changing the first input ....that simply replaces the second input element with the value. Though `.text()` is the good one....should have thought before......updated with that. Thanks.

Comment: `$(this).closest("td").nextAll("[class$=diff")`